# MySQL left join returns multiple rows, I want one row

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-concat

I've got two tables:

Orders table: `opdrachten`

Members table: `opdrachten_planning`

The member table only has `medewerker.id` (member id) and `opdrachten.id` (order id).

The following code returns multiple rows:

```
SELECT A.* , B.`opdracht` , B.`medewerker` FROM `opdrachten` AS A LEFT JOIN `opdrachten_planning` AS B ON B.`opdracht` = A.`id` WHERE A.`status`='actief'
```

**Returns:**

Location Amsterdam medewerker 22

Location Amsterdam medewerker 36

**What I want:**

Location Amsterdam medewerker 22, 36

I tried `group_concat` but can't get that to work. Can you help me? Tx!

Answer (score -1):

`GROUP_CONCAT` seems to lead to the result you are looking for. I added a `GROUP BY` clause to your query to make the aggregation work.

```
SELECT 
    A.*, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(B.medewerker)
FROM opdrachten AS A 
LEFT JOIN opdrachten_planning AS B 
    ON B.opdracht = A.id 
WHERE 
    A.status='actief';
GROUP BY A.id;
```

Comment: Tx Nomad i will try that